# Can't install gem 'jumpstart_auth' (Screenshot posted as well)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

[Screenschot of the error in my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hC2Zh.png)

I am trying to install the gem however it wont let me due to some error , tried reading the gem documentation but couldn't figure it out myself.Thats when I needed the help of the seasoned ones.

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>   ERROR:  Error installing jumpstart_auth:
>       ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
```

/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20161223-26375-4etqmc.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/gem_make.out

Comment: I would very much recommend installing Ruby with rvm: http://rvm.io rather than using system ruby and installing gems with sudo. It's recipe for disaster.

Comment: ...or `rbenv`, a bit easier I find

Comment: I am using rvm I forgot if ive used rvm to install ruby

Comment: pretty sure I installed ruby using rvm not the ubuntu package manager which is 'apt-get' . I just couldnt remember it and dont really know yet how to use rvm in different/switchin to different versions is ther a usefull link I could read about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gem is trying to compile an extension that use native C code. To do that, it looks for the C header file `ruby.h` which is not included in the regular Ruby runtime packages found in Ubuntu.

You probably installed Ruby using your distributions package manager. In that case you also need to install the corresponding `-dev` package.

In case you're using Ubuntu, it should probably be:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby2.3-dev
```

But, as already commented by @Esse, using RVM or rbenv is usually the better way to go.
Also, the screenshot you provided shows that you used `sudo` to install the gem. This should also not be necessary and is indeed bad practice. Using RVM/rbenv will also get around this.

Comment: That helped , Can you please explain why do I need to do that?How do I read that error in a human readable form , I couldnt translate the error yet myself without googling it or looking the error in stackoverflow

Comment: I added a few lines more. The important line from the output is `mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at...`

Comment: how do you do that using rvm ? and I tried to update my rvm using the latest version it let me ..

Comment: First it might be a good idea to clean up any data from the systems package manager (`dpkg --purge ruby2.3 ruby2.3-dev` and other packages it might have installed). Then you can do `rvm install 2.3` and `rvm use 2.3@awesomeproject --create`. Afterwards, calling `gem` or any executable belonging to a gem (like `bundle`) will - if RVM is installed properly - use the RVM version.

Comment: thanks one more thing I am trying to use the twitter API but , its like a microblogger however when i run it wont let me saying this error s

Comment: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/twitter-5.17.0/lib/twitter/rest/response/raise_error.rb:12:in `on_complete': Application cannot perform write actions. Contact Twitter Platform Operations through https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform (Twitter::Error::Forbidden)

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with this gem. The [README](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/README.md) suggests however: 
> make sure to set the correct access level, otherwise you may see the error: `Read-only application cannot POST`
This might be related?

Comment: thanks I have to do a lot of reading , and tring to understand and getback to this question/thread @thanks!

Comment: If you have a question regarding that twitter gem, better create a new question and mark this thread as resolved.

Comment: Absolutely right , this issue has been resolved and learned how to use rvm now and its workflow instead of using the package manager . And yeah another issue on the twitter gem can't get it right.

Comment: I would just like to ask some reputation about the way I asked and respond to threads thanks.